# How to make line numbers appear in python IDLE 3.10

Tags: python, python-idle, line-numbers

So, I was trying to make the line numbers appear in the Python IDLE, which I searched how to do in google, and found out that I should go to Options --> configuration IDLE --> General, except there is no General tab. Can someone please tell me if there are other ways I can make the line numbers appear in Python IDLE ver. 3.10?

I've tried to make the line numbers appear by checking the "Show line numbers in new windows" under the Shell/ED tab through configuration IDLE, and hitting apply, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#setting-preferences

Comment: What happens if you close IDLE after "Show line numbers in new windows" and then reopen it? I just tried it in version 3.10 and it worked (3.10 also gives a more direct way of showing line numbers. It, or some other recent version, has made some nice improvements to IDLE.)

Comment: A couple of years ago, the over-full General tab was split into Windows and Shell/Ed tabs.  The Apply button is mostly for seeing the effect of font changes in currently open windows without closing the dialog, so one can try other settings.  For most things, hit OK to exit and see the changes.  In current 3.10 to 3.12, the line number setting takes effect immediately after OK.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for the positive feedback.  We mostly hear from people who are not so happy.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy It is I who should be thanking you. For a while I was using Spyder (which I still use when I want to do something with numpy) but found it too complicated for my tastes. I switched back to IDLE, which is really the best choice for quick coding experiments. Thanks for helping to make it possible.